# How to know if a PhantomReference's referent is really GC-ed?

Tags: java, reference

I don't understand the spec from Java API:
"Phantom reference objects, which are enqueued after the collector determines that their referents may otherwise be reclaimed. 
...
An object that is reachable via phantom references will remain so until all such references are cleared or themselves become unreachable."
I wonder if a phantom reference's referent is always really reclaimed when the referent is only phantom-reachable.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
    public static void test() throws Exception {
        Object obj = new Object();
        ReferenceQueue<Object> refQueue =new ReferenceQueue<>();
        PhantomReference<Object> phanRef =new PhantomReference<>(obj, refQueue);
        obj=null;
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Reference ref = refQueue.remove();
        System.out.println(ref==phanRef);
     }
```

I found it always outputs "true". Does it mean that the object is in fact not GC-ed? To make sure the object is GC-ed, do we still need to call the PhantomReference's clear() method, so it will be GC-ed during next GC period?

Comment: Calling System.gc() does not guarantee that anything will happen. It is just a request for GC to be done.

Comment: @mwarren,here I assume GC will be done.

Comment: Are you just curious or is there some problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @zhuj9 I'm afraid you can't assume it is done. Unless you have definite confirmation it is done from a GC log.

Comment: @mwarren, I think GC is done at my side, coz I can see the phantom reference in the reference queue.

Comment: @Slaw, out of curiosity mainly, I also want to understand the phantom stuff better.

Comment: You seem to be just checking the reference, try checking the reference actually points at something or not.

Comment: @mwarren, since the reference got from the queue is a phantom one, by calling get() method will always return null.

Comment: I'm sorry I've lost track of what you are trying to prove. The phantom reference will not get GC'd, just what it is pointing to.

Comment: So you mean the phantom reference will not get GCed, the referent it's pointing to will be GCed? How to prove that?

Comment: If the reference was pointing to an object and then it isn't then the object it was pointing to has been GC'd.

Comment: So we still need know what's the object the phantom reference pointing to.

Comment: From the [`java.lang.ref`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html): "_Some time after the garbage collector determines that the reachability of the referent has changed to the value corresponding to the type of the reference, it will clear the reference and add it to the associated queue_". If I understand that correctly, a `PhantomReference` will only be cleared/enqueued once its referent becomes phantom reachable—and similarly for the other reference types (i.e. soft and weak).

Comment: And from the same documentation: "_An object is phantom reachable if it is neither strongly, softly, nor weakly reachable, it has been finalized, and some phantom reference refers to it_". So if a `PhantomReference` has been cleared/enqueued then the referent has those stated properties (i.e. phantom reachable, finalized). However, the referent may not have been reclaimed yet; from immediately after that sentence: "_Finally, an object is unreachable, and therefore eligible for reclamation, when it is not reachable in any of the above ways_".

Comment: So, again if I understand the documentation correctly, using the various `Reference` classes don't tell you if the referent has been fully reclaimed by the garbage collector. They only tell you when the referent has become _XXX_ reachable. In any case, one usually does not care about when objects are reclaimed, only that they can be when needed. It is possible to tune the garbage collector, and even choose an implementation, via VM options but that has to do with performance and not with hooking into the process.